# SAS Creating disjoint data sets using SET

Tags: sas

Is there a way in sas to create disjoint data sets using the `SET` statement?
I have tried:

```
DATA OnlyFirst OnlySecond InBoth;
SET  firstds(IN=A)
     seconds(IN=B);
IF A AND NOT B THEN OUTPUT OnlyFirst;
IF B AND NOT A THEN OUTPUT OnlySecond;
IF A AND B THEN OUTPUT InBoth;
Run;
```

But this does not create disjoint sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how the `set` statement works.  You should be able to use a `merge` if you first make sure firstds and seconds are both sorted by a key variable (or variables) they both share.  You'd then need to reference that shared variable in a `by` statement.

```
DATA OnlyFirst OnlySecond InBoth;
merge  firstds(IN=A)
    seconds(IN=B);
by <something shared variable>;
IF A AND NOT B THEN OUTPUT OnlyFirst;
IF B AND NOT A THEN OUTPUT OnlySecond;
IF A AND B THEN OUTPUT InBoth;
Run;
```